# Cannot convert string into float Python and code isn't producing the expected output

Tags: python, function, valueerror

Task

Given the meal price (base cost of a meal), 
tip percent (the percentage of the meal price being added as tip),
and tax percent (the percentage of the meal price being added as tax) for a meal,
find and print the meal's total cost.

Total meal Cost = meal cost + tip + tax )

```
def solve(meal_cost,tip_percent,tax_percent):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        meal_cost = float(input())

        tip_percent = int(input())

        tax_percent = int(input())

        tc = float(meal_cost + (tip_percent * meal_cost * 0.01) + (tax_percent * 0.01 * meal_cost))

        print(round(tc))

solve(12,20,8)
```

The expected output isn't produced from the code. Can Anyone explain this error?.
Error Message is "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '' ".

Comment: Your string contains a space somewhere. This is not possible: `float(' ')`.

Comment: Make sure to validate the input, or catch the exception and try again.

Also, you can remove the line `if __name__ ...` entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error comes from the `input()` function.
Once you use the `solve` function, the `input()` functions are expecting values, but you probably type Enter to make `solve` moving forward. Solve enterprete enter and raise an ValueError.

You should write your code like this:

```
def solve(meal_cost,tip_percent,tax_percent):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        meal_cost = float(meal_cost)
        tip_percent = int(tip_percent)
        tax_percent = int(tax_percent)
        tc = float(meal_cost + (tip_percent * meal_cost * 0.01) + (tax_percent * 0.01 * meal_cost))
        print(round(tc))

solve(12,20,8)
15
```

However if you really want your function to be interactive using the `input()` function, you could write it that way:

```
def solve():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        meal_cost = float(input("enter meal_cost value : "))
        tip_percent = int(input("enter tip_percent value : "))
        tax_percent = int(input("enter tax_percent value : "))
        tc = float(meal_cost + (tip_percent * meal_cost * 0.01) + (tax_percent * 0.01 * meal_cost))
        print(round(tc))

solve()
```

By the way, no need to write `if __name__ == '__main__':` inside your function ;-)

Comment: Glad that helped !!! Don't forget the little +1 by clicking on the top arrow. Thx ;-)